# phpmyadmin apache auth not working

Tags: apache-2.2

In Ubuntu, I added my usual directory Auth for phpmyadmin in the apache sites-available website specific file. (using Chrome incognito mode to ensure I was prompted) but I have no luck referencing the symlink below, nor where the symlink originates: /usr/share/phpmyadmin

Also tried adding it into: /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf

I restarted apache each time, works with all my other directories, but not phpmyadmin.

```
    <Directory "/srv/www/html/phpmyadmin">
            AuthType Basic
            AuthName "Restricted Files"
            AuthBasicProvider file
            AuthUserFile /srv/www/pwadmin
            Require user admin
    </Directory>
```

Comment: Does directory "/srv/www/html/phpmyadmin" in apache configuration perhapse have set "AllowOverride None" ?

Comment: I had a good look for that, and it is only at the parent directory "/srv/www/html/". However as suggested (somewhat) by Abhishek, I added "AllowOverride All" above "AuthType Basic" and it worked! This doesn't make sense to me - as my other directories at the same level don't need this. I'm guessing "AllowOverride None" is somewhere phpmyadmin specific that I couldn't find. As suggested in recent apache articles, I don't use .htaccess files, but rather I fill out the config in "sites-available".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under the directory section, add the line “AllowOverride All” under “Directory Index”.

Make Sure you have .htaccess file with below content.

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted Files"
AuthUserFile /path/to/passwords/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, that worked! Except I didn't need to use the .htaccess file, just added “AllowOverride All” above "AuthType" in the config for sites-available. Cheers!